# How to update listview using cursor while user enters text

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter

I'm totally stumped! I've been searching for ages, but can't find a solution. I have a feeling it is going to be really easy though!

Anway, I have a listview which is bound to a cursor, and every time the user enters a letter i want the listview to search the database and return the results. It sounds pretty easy, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {


    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "headwords._id";
    public static final String KEY_WORDS = "headwords.words";
    private ListAdapter adapter;
    private DbManager myDb;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_list);


        myDb = new DbManager(this);
        myDb.open();
        Cursor mCursor = myDb.startsWith("a");
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);



        try {
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCursor, 
                new String[] { KEY_WORDS, KEY_ROWID },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
                setListAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("adapter error Here!", ">>>>>>>>>>> Error!" + e.toString());
        }








        EditText myET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        myET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //code which would change listview to only show item that match what is being typed in
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {    
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: make your mCursor final and call mCursor.requery() in onTextChanged;

Comment: requery won't work because it won't be the same query as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make mCursor a member:

```
private Cursor mCursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  mCursor = myDb.startsWith("a");
}
```

Then in my example I am taking the first letter of the CharSequence but this might not be what you want to do but the key is the changeCursor();

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  mCursor = myDb.startsWith(s.toString.substring(0,1));
  adapter.changeCursor(mCursor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to anser and being so speedy! This code looks great, but eclipse is saying that the method ChangeCursor is undefined for the type ListAdapter. Any ideas why?

Comment: your adapter member should be cast as a SimpleCursorAdapter. So change  private ListAdapter adapter; to  private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

Comment: duh! I think it's time for me to go to bed. Thanks for the help, I got it working perfectly now, even if it's a bit slow. BTW, Mr. Hat rulz!

Comment: dont forget to mark this as an answer. it increases your reputation!